# Ignore forign key mapping in Model Class while fetching data

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Model Class which connects to 2 Other Models using one to many relation mapping.

How can i get the data's from just one class.?

**For Eg:**

```
ModelClass1(){

@oneToMany
Model_Class_2

@OneToMany
Model_Class_3

}
```

here if i execute this query

```
hibernateTemplate.find(from Model_Class_1);
```

It will fetch data's from Model_Class1, Model_Class_2, Model_Class_3.

> **How can i fetch data's from `Just Model_Class_1` and `Model_Class_2` and IGNORE `Model_Class_3`**

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
Model_Class_3
```

By specifying the fetch type, you can restrict the data fetch for the classes only required for your use. Refer the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html) of `FetchType` for more info.